# mp4 videos not streaming on site

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, mp4, jwplayer

I am using jwplayer to play mp4 videos on my site. The files are huge. They dont start streaming until the whole video has buffered. I need the videos to stream and buffer at the same time.

I read all forums and they mentioned about moving the metadata from the end to the start of the file using some external software like qtfaststart.

Apart from using a software like qtfaststart is there any other method for the developers to code and make the mp4 videos to stream on site?

Maybe with the help of FFmpeg or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish that with FFMPEG alone, we are currently using MP4Box. If your development team is working on linux, there are [several guides](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=mp4box+linux+install) on compiling and installing it.

From the [MP4Box site](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/):

> MP4Box can be used to prepare files for different delivery protocols, mainly HTTP downloading or RTP streaming.
>
> To prepare a file for HTTP download, the following instruction will interleave file data by chunks of 500 milliseconds in order to enable playback while downloading the file (HTTP FastStart):
>
> **MP4Box -inter 500 file.mp4**

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -c copy -movflags faststart outfile.mp4
```

or

```
mp4box -ipod infile.mp4
```

or

```
qt-faststart infile.mp4 outfile.mp4
```